# Why does redefining a module-level variable cause earlier usages to raise UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

I would like help understanding the difference between these two code snippets:

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 1


modlevel = Test()


def bound():
    assert modlevel.test == 1


bound()
```

^^ that runs without error

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 1


modlevel = Test()


def unbound():
    assert modlevel.test == 1
    modlevel = Test()


unbound()
```

^^ that fails with `UnboundLocalError`(!)

How does the line after the assertion affect the previous line?

Answer (score 1):

This does not *"redefine a module level variable"*:

```
modlevel = Test()


def unbound():
    assert modlevel.test == 1
    modlevel = Test()
```

What it does is, it defines a local `modlevel` variable in `unbound` function.

The error is caused because the local `modlevel` is accessed in `assert` line, before the local variable is initialized.

To modify the global `modlevel`, you need to do this:

```
def unbound():
    global modlevel
    assert modlevel.test == 1
    modlevel = Test()
```

Comment: What I still don't understand is why the first example works without the `global` statement

Comment: @DustinRasener In the first example you don't assign something to `modlevel`. When you do `modlevel = something` that triggers `modlevel` to become a local variable. Without that, the global variable is used.